# Are the linear velocities of rotating disc and hanging mass equal?

Tags: angular-momentum, energy-conservation, moment-of-inertia

[image: System]

In that picture there is a system that shows a disc that is rotating due to the work done by gravity on the mass hanging on the pulley.

There is no friction or any other non-conservative force acting on the system, so the total mechanical energy of the system is conserved.

The inital mechanical energy of the system is,

$$E_{i}=mgh_1$$

and the final mechanical energy of the system is,

$$E_f=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh_2$$

$I: \text{Moment of inertia of the rotating disc.}$

$\omega: \text{Magnitude of the angular velocity of the rotating disc.}$

$m: \text{Mass of the hanging object.}$

$v: \text{Magnitude of the linear velocity of the hanging object.}$

Due to conservation of the energy theorem, the initial energy of the system must be equal to final energy of the system.

$$E_i=E_f$$

$$mgh_1=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh_2$$

$$mgh_1-mgh_2=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$mg\Delta{h}=\frac{1}{2}I\omega^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$v(\text{of the rotating disc})=v_d=\omega R$$

$$\omega=\frac{v_d}{R}$$

$R: \text{Radius of the rotating disc.}$

$$mg\Delta{h}=\frac{1}{2}I(\frac{v_d}{R})^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

$$mg\Delta{h}=\frac{1}{2}I\frac{v_d^2}{R^2}+\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$

My question is, are the magnitude of the linear velocity of rotating disc $(v_d)$ and the magnitude of the hanging mass $(v)$ equal?

Answer (score 1):

No v is the velocity at the smaller inner wheel ,